# Drawable with more than two colors in XML?

Tags: android, android-layout

[image]

How to achieve this in drawable in XML android?
Bottom is transparent.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this in drawable in XML.

Firstly, you need to create a drawable file.

Then, add these lines of code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:color="#00000000">

<item>

    <shape android:shape="rectangle">

        <padding
            android:left="10dp"
            android:right="10dp"/>

        <gradient
            android:startColor="@color/purple_500"
            android:endColor="@color/purple_200"
            android:angle="0"/>

    </shape>

</item>

<item>

    <shape android:shape="rectangle">

        <gradient
            android:startColor="@color/white"
            android:angle="90"/>

    </shape>

</item>

</ripple>
```

Then use the drawable file anywhere in android.

[image: How it looks.]

Comment: I also need transparent in bottom.

Comment: Okay i will do that too.

Comment: @AnchalAjay I have implemented it with 3 colors. If it helps you please accept the answer.

Comment: No, I am still unable to make the bottom part transparent.

Comment: use hex code #00000000 for transparent in 2nd gradient but i will prefer to use the background color over transparent.